# How can I use the grid geometry node with a collection and fill in every spot at an equal distance

Tags: geometry-nodes

Sorry for the bad title, but sort of like this image

[image]

I want them to sort of match up to each other, when I just use a grid it's a set distance. I started geonodes yesterday, but I just want to know what nodes I would use for something like this.

Comment: Do you want to create a grid that looks like a brick wall with edges as joints? Maybe add what you have and what a result you expect because the question is not clear (to me at least). What is the collection mentioned in the title?

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I found a solution that works well enough for what I'm doing. What I meant by my question is I want each brick to have a random x scale but still all fill in from the same distance. Ignore the collection because I thought you couldn't randomize the size through geo nodes but now know I can so that doesn't matter.